# Using @Component instead of declarative declaration?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-annotations

i was using declarative way to make beans the spring managed.It works fine. I am planning to go annotattion way now.
I followed this [Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/)

What i did  is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">


     <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

</beans>
```

And used the Component annotation

```
@Component
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {}
```

But when i start my web application i get below error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Nullable
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)But when is start my web application i get  below error
```

**UPDATE:-** On google i found out that javax.annotation.Nullable can be found under jsr305-1.3.7.jar. But i think absence of jsr305-1.3.7.jar is not a problem as i could make it work in simple spring hello world project without the presence of jsr305-1.3.7.jar.So i think problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: put  jsr305-1.3.7.jar in classpath and try

Comment: which spring version jar ur using ?

Comment: i am using spring 3.1.1

Comment: i too downloaded that project it is based on spring-2.5.6.jar ...

Answer (score 0):

Add `jsr305-1.3.7.jar` to your classpath. You are getting the exception since the `JVM` is not able to find the required class

Comment: This is no where related to the spring jars. You need to ensure that you have all the required jars in the classpath